# Azure Virtual Machine West Europe region

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to start a virtual machine in West Europe region, but for some reason that regions isn't available in the drop down.

I have created Azure Web apps in West Europe, but I can't create a VM there. The only available regions are Central US, South Central US, East Asia, SouthEasts Asia and West Japan.

My subscription is Pay-as-you-Go (if that makes any difference).

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure subscription support issue, not a programming question.

Comment: Yes, it is. That's why I've put it under the "Azure" and "Azure-virtual-machine" tags, which I assume exist on stack overflow because people are interested in these kinds of issues. But thank you for for the valuable input :)

Comment: It's 100% off-topic. Absolutely zero to do with programming, and from what your answer states, 100% due to service-side issues (which are transient, and specific to your case, and not a topic for StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticket earlier today and seems they are having a capacity or other sort of issue. New subscriptions have West Europe disabled. With a ticket you can ask Microsoft to enable it for you. They will ask you how many VMs (and which types) you expect to provision. They expect processing the form can take up to two days. So far the unlimited cloud capacity on demand

Comment: Today I they opened up West Europe for me: "I am glad to inform you that our capacity planning team have enabled the West Europe region for your Subscription"

Answer (score 1):

You have to open a billing support ticket to have them enable the region(s) for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try now :)

Comment: This should be a comment - it's not an answer.